# Скрытие элемента при клике вне блока на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать скрытие блока при клике за пределами этого блока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы можем удалять класс `.active` с блока `.menu` при клике за пределами данного блока и его потомков. Привожу пример на нативном JavaScript:

```
var
    menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0];

// Menu Close
function menuClose() {
    menu.classList.remove('active');
}

// Menu Close Click Outside
function menuCloseClickOutside(e) {
    if(!e.target.matches('.menu, .menu *')) {
        menuClose();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('click', menuCloseClickOutside);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', menuCloseClickOutside);
```

На класс `.active` вы повесите свойство `display: block`, тогда как блок `.menu` будет изначально иметь свойство `display: none`. Также вы можете пойти по другому пути и наоборот добавлять класс, который будет скрывать блок.

При необходимости можно доработать данный пример на удаление блока с DOM, однако скрытие по классу будет наиболее эффективным с точки зрения производительности.